# Suggest a TAG synonym: SSO and merge

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

I Don't have enough rep to suggest it, but I think it's needed:

[sso](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sso) should be a synonym for: [single-sign-on](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-sign-on)

Comment: I second this motion.

Answer (score 1):

[sso](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sso) Synonymized into [single-sign-on](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-sign-on)